# Why pandas read_csv issues this warning? (elementwise comparison failed)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy, warnings

I have a set of led data saved on disk (led.csv) as such:

```
 , LEDC1, LEDC2, LEDC3
0, 54859, 11349, 56859
1, 54850, 12135, 56890
2, 54836, 12400, 56892
3, 54840, 15725, 56897
4, 54841, 19038, 56896
5, 54837, 21232, 56911
.,  ... ,  ... ,  ...
```

I am reading this data from .csv using pandas *read_csv* function:

```
data = pd.read_csv("Data/led.csv", index_col=0)
```

Providing the **index_col** argument to this function issues the following (numpy) warning:

```
C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py:466: 
FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
mask |= (ar1 == a)
```

---

What is the proper way of reading a .csv file with existing index using Pandas?

Any insight on the warning is much appreciated...

Comment: I tried it reading a file with random numbers, setting this numbers as id. It works until 1.000.000 numbers, on 1.000.001 I had this error.

Answer (score 4):

This is one way to get the same result as with index_col = 0 but without the warning. It may not be the most concise way though:

```
data = pd.read_csv("Data/led.csv")
data.set_index([data.columns.values[0]], inplace=True)
data.index.names = [None]
```

[This is a great post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46721064/11254707) on the type of error and, below it, there is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51933685/11254707) for a named column, e.g., index_col=['0'])

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly why you have an error, though a guess is it could occur if you have numeric and non-numeric data in your index column. Then `numpy` gets confused when it tries to check whether the index is ordered.

A possible hack:

```
data = pd.read_csv("Data/led.csv")

# assuming first column is named '0'
data['0'] = data['0'].astype(int).fillna(0)
data = data.set_index('0')
```

Answer (score 1):

From this discussion, it looks like there is a stray warning in `numpy` that the developers want to remove: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6784

My guess (without digging into the `pandas` source code) is that `pandas` is first asking whether `0` is a column name (perhaps with `0 in df.columns` or something) and then falling back to using `0` as an index when that query returns `False`.

Hopefully either `numpy` will remove the warning or `pandas` will adjust its logic in the future.