# Removing rows whose index match certain values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time


tic = time.time()
```

I read a long file of the headers [meter] [daycode] [meter reading in kWh]. A time series of over 6,000 meters.

```
consum = pd.read_csv("data/File1.txt", delim_whitespace=True, encoding = "utf-8", names =['meter', 'daycode', 'val'], engine='python')
consum.set_index('meter', inplace=True)
```

Because I have in fact total 6 files of this humungous size, I want to filter out those with insufficient information. These are the time series data with [meter] values under code 3 by category. I can collect this category information from another file. Following is where I extract this.

```
id_total = pd.read_csv("data/meter_id_code.csv", header = 0, encoding="cp1252")
#print(len(id_total.index))
id_total.set_index('Code', inplace=True)
id_other = id_total.loc[3].copy()

print id_other
```

And this is where I write to csv to check whether the last line is correctly performed:

```
id_other.to_csv('data/id_other.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
print consum[~consum.index.isin(id_other)]
```

Output: (of print id_other)

[image]

## Problem:

- I get the following warning. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659212/futurewarning-elementwise-comparison-failed-returning-scalar-but-in-the-futur) it says it didn't affect the code from working but mine is affected. I checked the correct directory (earlier confused my remote connection to gpu server with my hardware) and csv file was created. It turns out the meter IDs in the file are not filtered.

[image]

How can I fix the last line?

Comment: I think I fixed this by specifying the column name in the file by `id_other(['ID'])`, currently checking

Comment: The file is way too long to check manually lol. Should I just trust this function and proceed with the rest?