# Python: Group two columns together and find sum of third column

Tags: python, input, group-by, sum

Really new to python and need a bit of help with a question I have to complete.

I need to find the average earned per time period (month/year), based on a user input for month (MM) and year (YYYY).

I have the inputs as follows:

```
year_value = int(input("Year (YYYY): "))
month_value = int(input("Month (MM): "))
```

My dataframe looks like this:

```
Race_Course   Horse Name      Year   Month   Day   Amount_won_lost   Won/Lost
Aintree       Red Rum         2017   5       12    11.58             won
Punchestown   Camelot         2016   12      22    122.52            won
Sandown       Beef of Salmon  2016   11      17    20.0              lost
Ayr           Corbiere        2016   11      3     25.0              lost
Fairyhouse    Red Rum         2016   12      2     65.75             won
Ayr           Camelot         2017   3       11    12.05             won
Aintree       Hurricane Fly   2017   5       12    11.58             won
Punchestown   Beef or Salmon  2016   12      22    112.52            won
Sandown       Aldaniti        2016   11      17    10.0              lost
etc.
```

I have two problems:

1. how do I group the data together based on the inputs and sum the Amount_won_lost values that match, and
2. how do I make sure that when summing the values together that the value in Amount_won_lost is negative when Won/Lost = lost and stays positive for when Won/Lost = won

Any help would be very much appreciated! I've been stuck on this for a few hours and can't seem to figure it out.

The output should look something like this, but anything that prints the result would be perfect, I don't mind how it looks:

```
Year    Month    Amount_won_lost
2016    11       €-55.00
```

Comment: Pandas should be the way to go i think.

Comment: @Paandittya do you know what function in Pandas I should use? Sorry I don't know where to look!

Comment: Here is a [link](https://www.shanelynn.ie/summarising-aggregation-and-grouping-data-in-python-pandas) that quickly talks about grouping the data in a dataframe loaded to pandas.

Comment: @Paandittya thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first change the signs of your `Amount_won_lost` attribute by using `pd.DataFrame.apply()`

So for the following line:

```py
df["Amount_won_lost"] = df.apply(lambda x: -x["Amount_won_lost"] \
    if x["Won/Lost"] == "lost" else x["Amount_won_lost"], axis = 1)
```

It will replace your Amount_won_lost column with either a positive or negative value depending on if they won or lost.

And by utilizing `sum()` function mentioned in the other comments, you can get the sum for the Amount_won_lost for that given year and month.

The following will select all the values at your inputted values:

```py
df[(df["Year"] == year_value) & (df["Month"] == month_value)]
```

The output would be this:

```py
  Race_Course       HorseName  Year  Month  Day  Amount_won_lost Won/Lost
2     Sandown  Beef of Salmon  2016     11   17            -20.0     lost
3         Ayr        Corbiere  2016     11    3            -25.0     lost
8     Sandown        Aldaniti  2016     11   17            -10.0     lost
```

`print(df[(df["Year"] == year_value) & (df["Month"] == month_value)]["Amount_won_lost"].sum())`

will print `-55.0`.

If you had wanted to see the sums for every given month in a year, without using user inputs, the `groupby` function is your best bet!

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer Karm! I entered the four lines of code that you have above but got an error saying that 'year' wasn't defined in the last line of code (the print function). I swapped in `year_value` for `year`, and got the following error: `FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  result = method(y)
assignment1.py:103: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.`. Do you know how I would fix this? Sorry I'm really not sure how to fix this!

Comment: @awhelton did you also change month to month_value?

Comment: @awhelton You will also have to assign ```df[df["Year"] == year_value][df["Month"] == month_value]``` to it's own variable such as ```df2```. Otherwise, it will perform the actions but not store the result anywhere. You should then run the following: ```print(df2[df2["Year"] == year][df2["Month"] == month]["Amount_won_lost"].sum())```.

Comment: how do I assign `df[df["Year"] == year_value][df["Month"] == month_value]` to its own variable do I write `df2 = df[df["Year"] == year_value][df["Month"] == month_value]` ?

Comment: @awhelton yup! :)

Comment: I've tried that and I'm getting 0.0 as a result for all of the inputs - will I copy in all the code I have so you could check it?

Comment: @awhelton sure!

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv('edit_results.csv') / 
    year_value = input("Year (YYYY): ") / 
    month_value = input("Month (MM): ") / 
df = pd.read_csv('edit_results.csv') / 
    df["Amount_won_lost"] = df.apply(lambda x: -x["Amount_won_lost"] /
    if x["Won/Lost"] == "lost" else x["Amount_won_lost"], axis = 1) / 
    df2 = df[df["Year"] == year_value][df["Month"] == month_value] / 
    df3 = df2[df2["Year"] == year_value][df2["Month"] == month_value]["Amount_won_lost"].sum() / 
    print(df3)` . I've separated each line with /. Thanks Karm :)

Comment: @awhelton Your ```df3 = df2[df2["Year"] == year_value][df2["Month"] == month_value]["Amount_won_lost"].sum()``` needs to modified to ```df3 = df2["Amount_won_lost"].sum()```. I gave you the wrong advice earlier. Since you assigned df2 to it's own variable, you no longer needed to do the transforms again. Apologies. Let me know if this works!

Comment: No don't worry at all Karm, thanks for your help. I've made that change and this is what I get: `assignment1.py:101: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index. / 
  df2 = df[df["Year"] == year_value][df["Month"] == month_value] / 
0.0 `
So still not working unfortunately. I'll try a few more things. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @awhelton swap the line ```df2 = df[df["Year"] == year_value][df["Month"] == month_value``` for ```df2 = df[(df["Year"] == year_value) & (df["Month"] == month_value)]``` I am not getting any errors with this. This again seems to be an error in my suggestion, Apologies for making this way harder than it needed to be.

Comment: okay no more errors! Still getting 0.0 as the output for every input though :(

Comment: @awhelton Not sure then honestly. This is the code I have and it is outputting for the 2016, 11 case. ```df["Amount_won_lost"] = df.apply(lambda x: -x["Amount_won_lost"] if x["Won/Lost"] == "lost" else x["Amount_won_lost"], axis = 1) \
print(df[(df["Year"] == year_value) & (df["Month"] == month_value)]["Amount_won_lost"].sum())``` Sorry I couldn't figure it out, it must be some simple error that you should be able to get after troubleshooting some more

Comment: was looking over everything again and I found the problem! I needed to change the inputs to integers because of a conflict between python and numpys. Changed the inputs to `year_value = int(input("Year (YYYY): "))
month_value = int(input("Month (MM): "))`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @awhelton Great to hear! Sorry I didn't catch that. Yes, when you use input to get a value entered from the user, it will be a String, hence why you need to cast it to an Integer using ```int()```. Happy to see you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
by_year = race_data[race_data['Year']==year_value ]
by_month = by_year[by_year['Month']==year_value ]
print(by_month['Amount_won_lost'].sum())
```

i hope it helps

ps : data is a pandas DataFrame

Comment: Hi nassim, I tried this but I got this error:   `File "assignment1.py", line 91, in 
    average_amount_spent_per_period
     by_year = data[data['Year']==year_value ]
NameError: name 'data' is not defined`

Do you know how to define data? I have imported pandas but don't know what else to do

Comment: data is a dataframe that contains your dataset, can you please give me the name of the file you are loading your dataset from ? so that i update the answer accordingly

Comment: I load the data using this: `race_data = pd.read_csv('edit_results.csv')`

Comment: hi nassim, I tried that but got a different error and I don't know what it means. This is the error, `FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison /
  result = method(y) /
0.0` . Do you know what this means?

Comment: This is a numpy bug.In your case it could be triggered by pandas in some comparaison. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659212/futurewarning-elementwise-comparison-failed-returning-scalar-but-in-the-futur some one posted a realy good and detailed answer about this bug, you should read it