# Why does select raise a FutureWarning?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, future-warning

In my code I have a 2D numpy.ndarray filled with *numpy.str_* values. I'm trying to change values "null" to "nan" using the select method. The problem is that this method raises a FutureWarning.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659212/futurewarning-elementwise-comparison-failed-returning-scalar-but-in-the-futur). On a suggestion there I tried to not compare Python strings a Numpy strings, but convert Python string to Numpy string at the start. Obviously that doesn't help and I'm looking for an advice.

I would like to avoid shutting down the warning (as it is in the link). It seems to me like a very dirty approach.

My code snippet:

```py
import pandas_datareader as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt


start_date = dt.datetime(year=2013, month=1, day=1)
end_date = dt.datetime(year=2013, month=2, day=1)
df = pd.DataReader("AAA", "yahoo", start_date, end_date + dt.timedelta(days=1))
array = df.to_numpy()

null = np.str_("null")
nan = np.str_("nan")
array = np.select([array == null, not array == null], [nan, array])
print(array[0][0].__class__)
print(null.__class__)
```

```
C\Python\Project.py:13: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  array = np.select([array == null, not array == null], [nan, array])
<class 'numpy.str_'>
<class 'numpy.str_'>
```

I'm quite new to Python so every help will be appreciated. And also - if you have a better way how to achieve that, please let me know.

Thank you!

Edit: Sorry for that. Now it should work as it is.

Comment: Would it be possible to get an example of an initial value for `array` that triggers this issue? (Preferably a very short one, per the "minimal" part of the [mre] definition). As it is, the code isn't usable to test proposed fixes because it can't be run without changes (or rather, when run without changes, it produces an entirely different issue).

Comment: This code will return `'array' is not defined` as you are comparing something to `array` before you've defined `array`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 50 reputation yet, so I can't comment..

As I understand it you only want to change al `'null'`-entries to `'nan'` instead?

Your code creates a Numpy Array of float-values, but for some reason you expect strings of `'null'` in the array? 
Perhaps you should've written

```
array = df.to_numpy()
array = array.astype(str)
```

to make it more clear.

From here, the array consists only of strings, and to make the change from `'null'` to `'nan'`, you only have to write

```
array[array == 'null'] = 'nan'
```

and the warning is gone. You don't even have to use `np.select`.

If you want floating-point values in your array, you could use Numpy's own `np.nan` instead of a string, and do

```
array = array.astype(float)
```

The `nan`-strings are automatically converted to `np.nan`, which is seen as a float.