# FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; when dropping all rows from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to drop those rows in a dataframe that have value '0' in the column 'candidate'. Some of my dataframes only have value '0' in this column. I expected that in this case I will get an empty dataframe, but instead I get the following warning and the unchanged dataframe. How can I get an empty dataframe in this case? Or prevent returning an unchanged dataframe?

Warning message:

*C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py:253: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  res_values = method(rvalues)*

My code:

```
with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as file:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',')
    df.drop(df.index[(df['candidate'] == '0')], inplace=True)
    print(df)

     post id  ...  candidate
0          1  ...          0
1          1  ...          0
2          1  ...          0
3          1  ...          0
4          1  ...          0
..       ...  ...        ...
182       10  ...          0
183       10  ...          0
184       10  ...          0
185       10  ...          0
186       10  ...          0

[187 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: It's not an error, just a warning. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659212/futurewarning-elementwise-comparison-failed-returning-scalar-but-in-the-futur

Comment: A more natural way to drop would be `df.loc[df["candidate"]!="0"]`. It would probably avoid the warning as well

Comment: @AMH I tried this out, but unfortunately this dosen't change anything, I still get the warning and the same output

Comment: Maybe check your data types with `df.info()`, when reading the csv `candidate` should either be float or int

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your suggestions!

Indeed, the value type is `int`, but only if 0 is the only value in the column. Where other values are present, the type is `object`.

So I solved the problem by using:

`df = df.loc[(df["candidate"] != "0") & (df["candidate"] != 0)]`

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation tries to find rows from `Index` matching the condition. You should find the rows to match the condition first and then take its index:

```py
df.drop(df[df['candidate'] == 0].index, inplace=True)
```

After replacing the line your snippet should return:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [post id, ..., candidate]
Index: []
```

You should also check that the type of the column matches with the type of the value you are comparing to.

Comment: Unfortunately this has no impact.

Comment: Could it be that the type of `candidate` is `int` instead of `str`? I edited my answer to compare`0` instead of `'0'`.