# Pandas: Filter correctly Dataframe columns considering multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, feature-engineering

I have a data frame representing the customers ratings of restaurants. `star_rating` is rating of the customer in this data frame.

- What i want to do is to add a column `nb_favorables_mention` in the same data frame that represents **The total number of reviews that received at least one "useful" or "funny" or "cool" rating AND the rating of the review is> = 3.**

```py
data = {'rating_id': ['1', '2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],
        'user_id': ['56', '13','56','99','99','13','12','88','45'],
        'restaurant_id':  ['xxx', 'xxx','yyy','yyy','xxx','zzz','zzz','eee','eee'],
        'star_rating': ['2.3', '3.7','1.2','5.0','1.0','3.2','1.0','2.2','0.2'],
        'rating_year': ['2012','2012','2020','2001','2020','2015','2000','2003','2004'],
        'first_year': ['2012', '2012','2001','2001','2012','2000','2000','2001','2001'],
        'last_year': ['2020', '2020','2020','2020','2020','2015','2015','2020','2020'],
        'funny': ['1', '0','0','1','1','1','0','0','0'],
        'useful': ['1', '0','0','0','1','0','0','0','1'],
        'cool': ['1', '0','0','0','1','1','1','1','1'],

        }


df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['rating_id','user_id','restaurant_id','star_rating','rating_year','first_year','last_year','funny','useful','cool'])
df['star_rating'] = df['star_rating'].astype(float)



filtered_data = df[(df['star_rating'] >= 3) & (df['funny']==1 | df['useful']==1 | df['cool']==1)]
d = filtered_data.groupby('restaurant_id')['star_rating'].count().to_dict()

df['nb_favorables_mention'] = df['restaurant_id'].map(d)
df.head(20)
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with my syntax but from what i tried, i keep getting these error messages

- **ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**
- **TypeError: Cannot perform 'ror_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]**

What is the correct syntax considering what i'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an operator precedence issue; In python, `|` operator has higher precedence than `==`, wrapping comparison expressions in parenthesis should solve your problem, also since `funny`, `useful` and `cool` columns are str type, use string `'1'` instead of number `1`:

```
filtered_data = df[(df['star_rating'] >= 3) & ((df['funny']=='1') | (df['useful']=='1') | (df['cool']=='1'))]
```

[Check result here](https://uscript.co/public/Google_108617488638529745626/python/bd3c8962.py)

Besides using `|`, you can also compare multiple columns in one go and then check condition with `any`:

```
filtered_data = df[(df['star_rating'] >= 3) & df[['funny', 'useful', 'cool']].eq('1').any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: thank you for the answer I think it worked for my larger dataset, but i have a weird warning saying  `FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  return op(a, b).` Do you know what it means?

Comment: Is it coming from above code snippet or some other part of your code ?

Comment: Above the output when i do .head() on my Dataframe. from the first operation you pointed out.

Comment: You might want to check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659212/futurewarning-elementwise-comparison-failed-returning-scalar-but-in-the-futur

Comment: i know, in my larger Dataframe, the values in funny etc.. are not chars but integers