# Python,Pandas, - How to search for an integer in a column

Tags: python, pandas

This outwardly simple problem has been frustrating me for awhile.I am  new to python and  I can't get anywhere. I am looking to find a single integer in a specific one column of a large dataframe (600,000 records and 56 columns). Full match. I have recreated a simplified example here.

eg How to find the number 5440499367 (2nd row) in this dataframe (epi) and return the results.

```
    KEY
0   

1   5440499367
2   5040484761
3   5404390876
4   5444456006
5   5040507739
```

```
epi.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   KEY  6 non-null      int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 176.0 bytes
```

Using

```
epi["KEY"] == 5040501624
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
Name: KEY, dtype: bool
```

so thats fine, I have created a boolean series which has found the number.
When I try to do that in the large dataframe (I can't show that data because it has identifiers)

eg below, I get an error and an empty row 0x56 columns.

```
found = df[df["KEY"] == "5440499367"] 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py:68: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  return op(a, b)
```

I have tried also

```
5040501624 in epi["KEY"]
False
```

Which I feel is possibly the wrong use.
I wondered if this was a datatype issue and have checked that the dtype is Int64 and in the 600,000 rows there are no empty values.

What is the simplest way to do this ?

Comment: You want to find the integer, so `df[df["KEY"] == 5440499367]`?

Comment: your issue is that your casting it as a string, your first boolean was correct.

Comment: If I do df[df["KEY"] == 5440499367] then I get  0 rows.

Comment: what is `df` , is it same as `epi` in your example? if no then probably there is no such number in `df` as opposite to `epi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're accidentally comparing with a string version of the integer you're looking for. Instead of:

```
found = df[df["KEY"] == "5440499367"]
```

you should do what you were originally trying with boolean masking:

```
found = df[df["KEY"] == 5440499367]
```

As you said, the `dtype` of "KEY" column is `Int64`, so you should be comparing an integer to an integer. This `FutureWarning` is coming from `numpy`, and often occurs when you compare a `str` to some numeric values. [A detailed explanation of the warning can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659212/futurewarning-elementwise-comparison-failed-returning-scalar-but-in-the-futur)