# How To Resolve Future Warning Errors

Tags: python, data-science

I am using the python code :
`dataReg=pd.DataFrame(data.loc[data['Store']=='1'])` to extract the data of store 1.

But following warning encountered.

```
C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py:253: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  res_values = method(rvalues)
```

Can anyone suggest how to Resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659212/futurewarning-elementwise-comparison-failed-returning-scalar-but-in-the-futur

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are comparing an int in your table to a string in your code.  Try removing the '' from the statement.

Also if data is already a DataFrame you don't need to use pd.DataFrame again.

```
dataReg=data[data['Store']==1])
```

Answer (score -2):

Future Warnings is just a small warning which is not be to be concerned about
It can be ignored so it doesn't get displayed.

Try This code:

```
import warnings as w
w.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Comment: ```It can be ignored``` Do you have any reason to support this?

Comment: yeah. until the future warning is no longer a warning and the code is deprecated.