# Count frequency of values in a row?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, count

I have a data frame set up as shown below (this is an example, the original is much larger):

[image]

I am trying to answer the question, "How many rows have three true values? Two true values? One true value?"

I would prefer to do it in SQL but I am struggling to find a solution. I am also struggling to find a solution in Pandas using Python. I would be open to either solution at this point.

If anyone has any pointers, I will be greatly appreciative. I'm sure it's a simple solution, I just haven't learned it yet and I can't find the correct way to do it.

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example, and always post the actual data rather than an image of the data. You will receive higher quality answers if you don't ask folks to manually enter your test dataset.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
(df.isin(["TRUE"])).sum(axis=1).value_counts()
```

The part `df.isin(["TRUE"])` rather than `df == "TRUE"` is used to get around the issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659212/futurewarning-elementwise-comparison-failed-returning-scalar-but-in-the-futur).

**Example** Sample dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.choice(["TRUE", "FALSE"], (5, 5))
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df = df.reset_index()
print(df)
```

This gives:

```
   index      0      1      2      3      4
0      0   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE
1      1  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE
2      2   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
3      3  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE
4      4   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
```

Then

```
(df.isin(["TRUE"])).sum(axis=1).value_counts()
```

gives:

```
3    2
5    1
4    1
2    1
```

i.e. "TRUE" appears 3 times in 2 rows, 5 times in one row, 4 times in one row, and 2 times in one row.

Comment: Great solution but `df =="TRUE"` does not produce a future warning for your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a `LEFT` join of a `CTE` that returns all the possible outcomes (0, 1, 2, 3) to the table and aggregation.

If the data type of the columns `ValueX` is `TEXT`:

```
WITH cte(total) AS (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3))
SELECT c.total, COUNT(t.number) counter
FROM cte c LEFT JOIN tablename t
ON c.total = (t.ValueA = 'TRUE') + (t.ValueB = 'TRUE') + (t.ValueC = 'TRUE')
GROUP BY total
```

If you want the results in 1 row:

```
SELECT SUM(total = 0) total_0,
       SUM(total = 1) total_1,
       SUM(total = 2) total_2,
       SUM(total = 3) total_3
FROM (       
  SELECT (ValueA = 'TRUE') + (ValueB = 'TRUE') + (ValueC = 'TRUE') total
  FROM tablename
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=426ed8e0a7fb2e1189d8918215fe5222).

If the data type of the columns `ValueX` is `BOOLEAN` (or `INTEGER`):

```
WITH cte(total) AS (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3))
SELECT c.total, COUNT(t.number) counter
FROM cte c LEFT JOIN tablename t
ON c.total = t.ValueA + t.ValueB + t.ValueC
GROUP BY total
```

If you want the results in 1 row:

```
SELECT SUM(total = 0) total_0,
       SUM(total = 1) total_1,
       SUM(total = 2) total_2,
       SUM(total = 3) total_3
FROM (       
  SELECT ValueA + ValueB + ValueC total
  FROM tablename
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9b8df25782dfdbe9287def70943885e9).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if the values are strings, there is a hacky way of using string functions for this:

```
select 15 - length(A || B || C) as num_true, count(*)
from t
group by num_true;
```

This uses the fact that `TRUE` has 4 characters and `FALSE` has five, so this won't work in all languages.

You can incorporate this logic so the values are in separate columns:

```
select sum(15 = length(A || B || C) as true_0,
       sum(14 = length(A || B || C) as true_1,
       sum(13 = length(A || B || C) as true_2,
       sum(12 = length(A || B || C) as true_3
from t;
```