# How to find different values of different columns from the same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a dataframe structured like this one below:

```
        A      B         C                 D
group_997    NaN    Purple    JMHKJALJ_06538
group_998    NaN    Pink      JMHKJALJ_04556
group_999    NaN    Red       JMHKJALJ_09211
group_995    NaN    Green     JMHKJALJ_16378
group_996    NaN    Yellow    JMHKJALJ_81324
```

Now I'd like to find the corresponding value of `JMHKJALJ_16378` (column `D`) on column `A` (that is `group_995`).
I tried to use:

```
df[df['A'].str.contains('JMHKJALJ_16378')]
```

But the output is not correct.
How can I do that?

Comment: `df[df['D'].str.contains('JMHKJALJ_16378')]` Typeo - should be column `D` not `A`

Comment: Ok, and what if I would not know the column of `JMHKJALJ_16378`? Knowing only the value name `JMHKJALJ_16378` how could I obtain his corresponding value on column A?

Comment: Actually it works but I got this warning:
`FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison`, how can I obtain only the output ?

Comment: [It's considered a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46721064/14277722) I thought this was resolved in newer releases of `pandas`.

Comment: I upgraded pandas but apparently I still got this issue. What a mess However, thank you!

Comment: You can asked in another question if there is any development on this issue. I can't help with that, because I don't get the warning on google colab.