# How to get the index of numpy string array?

Tags: python

The numpy array is of strings and when I use

```py
 a = np.where(arr==yourelement)[0]
```

It gives me a future warning
that is

```
FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
```

What is this caused by?
Is this caused by the strings or something else???

arr is a string array like:
`arr = np.array["alex","james","andy"]`
yourelement is one of the elements chosen from the array arr
And now I want to know the index of yourelement in arr

Comment: Some useful comments and explanations to be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659212

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can not create a numpy array using `np.array["alex","james","andy"]` since it is an invalid syntax. [`np.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) is a function and thus, the correct way to create the desired numpy array is `np.array(["alex","james","andy"])`.

Assuming that we create an array successfully using:

```
import numpy as np 

x = np.array(["alex","james","andy"])
print(np.where(x == 3))
```

you are right - the comparison done with `np.where` returns an error:

> FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46721064/7789963), as pointed out in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74085364/how-to-get-the-index-of-numpy-string-array/74085737#comment130805270_74085364), will answer your question.

However, if you want to compare or find the index of an element which is of `str` data type, you won't get any error:

```
print(np.where(x == "3"))
```

returns: `(array([], dtype=int64),)` specifying that the data type of elements in the output object is [`int64`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html) even though the array/output is empty.

---

To get the index of an element in the numpy array, you might want to use [`numpy.argwhere`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html).  I have used `yourelement` as `"alex"` in this answer.

```
import numpy as np 

x = np.array(["alex","james","andy"])
print(np.argwhere(x == "alex")[0][0]) # This gives 0 as an output.
```

Using `np.argwhere` is helpful when you have more than one instance of an element in the list e.g.

```
y = np.array(["alex","james","andy", "alex"])
print(np.argwhere(y == "alex"))
```

gives: `[[0] [3]]`

Or you can convert `x` to list using `tolist` method and use `index` method to get the index of `yourelement`.

```
print(x.tolist().index("alex"))       # This gives 0 as an output.
```

Comment: The problem got solved, you are right about the comparison and the np.argwhere it helped me a lot, Thank you very much.