# Pandas Series String Comparison

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge dataframe in which I am filtering it on two conditions.

A reproducible toy example is as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
df_ = pd.DataFrame([["A",91,1], ["B",91,2], ["C",92,1]], 
                   columns=['Name','Iteration','IP Weight'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["D",91,1], ["E",91,1], ["F",91,1]], 
                   columns=['Name','Iteration','IP Weight'])
```

**Objective**
If `df_` rows have the same "iteration" and "ip_weight" combination as the 1st row of df, filter that and append df, here 1st row will get removed from `df_` and `df2` will get appended to it.

I filtered it as follows,

```py
df_[~((df_['Iteration']==df2['Iteration'][0]) & (df_['IP Weight']==df2['IP Weight'][0]))]
```

It runs fine in the notebook but when I put it in the script it fails with the message

> " FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison"

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: In the docker container, it's 1.0.3 while in local(notebook where it is working as expected) is '0.24.2'

Comment: Does this help [FutureWarning elementwise comparison failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659212/futurewarning-elementwise-comparison-failed-returning-scalar-but-in-the-futur)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the following mask:

```
msk = df_['Iteration'].eq(df2.loc[0, 'Iteration'])\
    & df_['IP Weight'].eq(df2.loc[0, 'IP Weight'])
```

I assume that the initial row in *df2* has index == *0*.
*True* value of this mask indicate rows to move from *df_* to *df2*.

Then append rows to be moved to *df2*:

```
df2 = df2.append(df_[msk], ignore_index=True)
```

And finally drop them from *df_*:

```
df_ = df_[~msk]
```

## Edit

Other, more concise way to create the mask is:

```
msk = df_.iloc[:, 1:].eq(df2.iloc[0, 1:]).all(axis=1)
```

This time it will work regardless of the index in the first row of *df2*.

Comment: How can I reach the same result without using "~"

Comment: Look at *df_ = df_[~msk]* in my answer. This is just what you ask for - an example of *boolean indexing* with **negated** mask.

Answer (score 1):

So when I run something like your example in my notebook as you say it runs fine - but I would note that in researching this I found this link:

[FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620175/futurewarning-elementwise-comparison-failed-returning-scalar-instead/36621575)

The top answer is informative. My best guess would be that maybe in your actual data some of the ints are recorded as strings?

For example, see my code below:

```
import pandas as pd
df_ = pd.DataFrame([["A",91,1], ["B",91,2], ["C",92,1]], 
                   columns=['Name','Iteration','IP Weight'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["D","91",1], ["E",91,1], ["F",91,1]], 
                   columns=['Name','Iteration','IP Weight'])

k=df_[((df_['Iteration']==df2['Iteration'][0]) & (df_['IP Weight']==df2['IP Weight'][0]))]

g=pd.concat([df2,k])

print(g)
```

By making the Iteration of the first row of df2 a string, I can recreate your error. Make it an integer and it works.